# How can I split up a long f-string in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, f-string

I am getting a *line too long* [PEP 8](https://pep8.org/) *E501* issue.

```
f'Leave Request created successfully. Approvers sent the request for approval: {leave_approver_list}'
```

I tried using a multi-line string, but that brings in a `\n`, which breaks my test:

```
f'''Leave Request created successfully.
Approvers sent the request for approval: {leave_approver_list}'''
```

How can I keep it single line and pass PEP 8 linting?

Comment: This is indeed a partial duplicate, but the duplicate does not pertain to f strings, a _slight_ modification is needed to that answer.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Use parentheses and [string literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation):

```
msg = (
    f'Leave Request created successfully. '
    f'Approvers sent the request for approval: {leave_approver_list}'
)
```

Note, the first literal doesn't need an `f`, but I include it for consistency/readability.

Comment: To add to that: [_"The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash for line continuation."_](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length)

Comment: The first line should not have an `f`

Comment: @AidanH why *should* it not? It makes no difference, so it comes down to a style choice. I prefer the `f` here so they line up. I can understand why people would feel otherwise, though. I actually *noted* this in the answer.

Comment: Some tools will complain if you have an f-string with no actual interpolation (pylint or mypy does this, I think). You may need to tell the tool to not complain about that line.

Comment: @paxdiablo `pylint` does, but I don't hink `mypy` does

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga *does* `pylint`? I don't think that does either, for  https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint  `v2.10.2` at least

Comment: When trying this approach, it generated string msg = 'Leave Request created successfully. "    "Approvers sent the request for approval: list' . Note the spaces in quotes in the middle. Why are these present in the strings in my case on python 3.10.7?

Comment: @MiroJanosik you are going to have to provide a [mcve]. Just guessing, butdid you use single quotes to start the string, and then accidentally used double quotes to try to end it? In any case, that is absolutely not what happens with the above code in Python 3.10

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - sorry, I can't reproduce it anymore.

Answer (score 20):

You will need a line break unless you wrap your string within parentheses. In this case, `f` will need to be prepended to the second line:

```
'Leave Request created successfully.'\
f'Approvers sent the request for approval: {leave_approver_list}'
```

Here's a little demo:

```
In [97]: a = 123

In [98]: 'foo_'\
    ...: f'bar_{a}'
Out[98]: 'foo_bar_123'
```

I recommend [juanpa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48881196/how-can-i-split-up-a-long-f-string-in-python/48881390#48881390) since it is cleaner, but this is one way to do this.

Comment: "But f will need to be prepended to the second line"- why?

Comment: @Chris_Rands Otherwise, the second line is treated as a literal string, and the variable is not substituted in.

Comment: In your answer, you have a multiline string, so it is not required.