# PEP8-conform splitting of long f-string

Tags: python, split, pep8, f-string

How to split the following long line into two lines, in order to conform to PEP8?

```
percentage = f"{state[0] / state[1] * 100:{3 + (decimals > 0) + decimals}.{decimals}f}%"
```

**Note:**
The f-string here cannot simply be split into two f-strings as suggested in the accepted answer to a [previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48881196/how-to-split-up-a-long-f-string-in-python), since this would break formatting. This question here hence needs a different and more general solution.

Comment: Just add a new line after "=" ->
 `percentage = \
    f"{state[0] / state[1] * 100:{3 + (decimals > 0) + decimals}.{decimals}f}"`

Comment: If you're that worried about PEP8 on a 88 character line, simply compute whatever's inside your f-string in the line above. And remember that [a foolish consistency is the hobgoblin of little minds](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't be afraid of using variables! It will make your code more readable.

```
a = state[0] / state[1] * 100
b = 3 + (decimals > 0) + decimals
# of course, you would change the names here
percentage = f"{a:{b}.{decimals}f}%"
```